# Dynamically load the components Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I am trying to load an array of components dynamically. I have an array which contains all the components that need to be load on run time. Following piece of code loops over the array and creates a factory for components.
`

```
gAfterViewInit() {
      this.loadcomponents();
  }
loadcomponents() {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.components.length; i++) {
          //this.sidetext[i] = this.components[i].sidetext;
          //this.section_ttile[i] = this.components[i].section_ttile;
          for (let j = 0; j < this.components[i].components.length; j++) {
              let termItem = this.components[i].components[j];
              let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(termItem.component);
              let viewContainerRef = this.termHost.viewContainerRef;
              viewContainerRef.clear();
              let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
              (<TermComponent>componentRef.instance).data = termItem.data;
          }
      }
```

`
And here is my template

```
            <div class="div_for_ques" *ngFor="let component of components; let i=index">

                <div class="sec_two">
                    <ng-template term-host></ng-template>
                </div>
            </div>
```

But the problem is that dynamically loaded components appears on top of previous loaded component component. I want each component to be in a its own seperate div. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?
Following is th current output.

[image]

Expected output is two such input fields but it is only second one which actually overlapped first one completely.

Comment: it would be helpful if you could post the image of resultant dom .

Comment: Check out this [**medium post**](https://medium.com/@aravindfz/load-modal-component-dynamically-in-angular-5fda8e1dc3e7)

Comment: @micronyks i have edited the question

Comment: @Aravind components are loading succssfully but former component overlaps later one

Comment: It's sounds more like a css issue.. Try to rap your *ngFor with div and set each child with display block so they will be one under another

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `@ViewChildren` so you get a query list of containers.

Your template could be like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let v of views">
   <div #target></div>
</div>
```

And your code will instance components like this:

```
@ViewChildren('target', {read: ViewContainerRef}) container: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>;

ngAfterViewInit(){
  this.container.toArray().map((viewContainerRef, i) => {
    let componentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.components[i]); // actually that should be this.components[i].components[j] something in your case
    let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
  });
}
```